# button action in listbox in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

I have a listbox where each row of listbox contains 2 textblock and 2 button.
Whenever i click 1st button of any row of listbox then it will show the text of 1st textblock of that row from the listbox and whenever i click the 2nd button of any row of listbox it will speak the text of the 1st textblock of that row.
Consider the bellow picture of listbox.If i click the star button of 2nd row it will show "sedulous" and if i click the the speaker button of the last row it will speak "underbid".
How can i do that???
My list looks like this:

[image]

My listbox design in xaml looks like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" FontSize="26" Width="400" Height="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Eng}" Width="150"/>
                            <Button Content="" Height="Auto" Name="b1" Width="100" BorderThickness="0" Background="DarkGreen" />
                              <Button Content="" Height="Auto" Name="b2" Width="100" BorderThickness="0" Background="DarkGreen" />  
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Bng}" Width="150"/>
                        <Rectangle Height="2" Width="400" Fill="YellowGreen" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And my code for making the list is:

```
List<dataLists> mylist = new List<dataLists>();

        string word = textBox1.Text;

        if (db != null)
        {

            var contacts = (from m in db.Dics where m.English.StartsWith(word) select new { m.English, m.Bangla }).Take(5);


            string s1, s2;

            try
            {

                foreach (var a in contacts)
                {
                    s1 = a.English;
                    s2 = a.Bangla;

                    mylist.Add(new dataLists() { Eng = s1, Bng = s2 });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

            listBox1.ItemsSource = mylist;
```

Can anyone have any solution of this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily manage this in button's onclick event, set tag as textblock's text and

in onclick event

textbox.text = (sender as button).Tag.Tostring()

Comment: Look my xaml file. Every row of my listbox contains 2 textblock and 3 button. SO whenever i click 2nd button of any row of listbox it will show the text of 1st textblock of that row. @techloverr

Comment: @DarkenShooter so what you need?

Comment: I updated my question.Please read my example i think it will be clear to u,what i want.help me there if u can.@techloverr

Comment: @DarkenShooter so follow my solution

Comment: @DarkenShooter bind the tag of button to textblock's text in xaml.

Comment: How to bind this?? And after binding what to do?? @techloverr

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42232/discussion-between-darkenshooter-and-techloverr)

Comment: @DarkenShooter  <Button Content="" Height="Auto" Name="b1" Width="100" BorderThickness="0" Background="DarkGreen" Tag="{Binding Path=Eng}"  />

Comment: then  i use this string c = (sender as button).Tag.Tostring(); it shows an error says "type or namespace of button could not be found" @techloverr

Comment: I fixed it using "((Control)sender).Tag.ToString();"

Comment: @DarkenShooter so done na then approve and upvote so one can use this